# View SQL generated by EJB Query object?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, toplink

Is there a way to view the underlying SQL generated by a javax.persistence.Query object?

In other words, I have the following EJB QL query:

```
SELECT f FROM FunkyObject f where f.id = 4
```

I would like to see something like this:

```
SELECT funky_object.id, funky_object.name, funky_object.some_int_col
  FROM funky_object
WHERE funky_object.id = ?
```

I see something like this in my log file when there's an error executing a query.

I would like to know how I can see the same info for a valid query.

I'm using EJB with TopLink on Sun Application Server (JEE5).

Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255541/show-generated-sql-in-toplink-in-eclipse

Comment: Thanks @raddykrish... Unfortunately my machine does't have any path that resembles the one mentioned in that thread.

Comment: hope you have already tried <property name="toplink.logging.level" value="FINE"/> in the persitence.xml

Comment: Yep, that did the trick.  I don't get the log file, but I added that property to my persistence.xml and started seeing my generated SQL. Got it working just before I left work... Just getting home to say thanks now!